# Sufficient condition for total nonnegativity

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

If $A$ is any $m \times n$ entrywise non negative matrix, is it true that, if all initial minors of $A$ are nonnegative then $A$ is totally nonnegative (TN)?

I know the analogous result is true for TP, i.e. if all initial minors of $A$ are positive then $A$ is totally positive (TP). I need help in the TN case. In case it's not, is it true for every Hankel matrix? Any proof, tip and/or suggestions or a counterexample will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by an "initial minor"?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I cant guve the definition here.  Please refer first paragraph 
of page 75 of https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KF1V4tnTRtwC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=initial+minor+of+a+matrix&source=bl&ots=6ZyWk4_md2&sig=ACfU3U1jzIfK85MjSVttO3kpEn0bQLDzyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-_anD_cDnAhXfxjgGHZmMB_oQ6AEwF3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=initial%20minor%20of%20a%20matrix&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true. Consider the Hankel matrix $\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&1&0}$ for instance.

Comment: Thanks for replying,  i want an entrywise nonnegative matrix,  I have edited it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.